# Change image src depending on an elements value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html

```
<div class="fake-input">
               <input type="text" data-theme="a" placeholder="Card Number" id="ccnumber" name="ccnumber" class="textBox input tokenex_data" data-form="ui-body-a" />

        <img id="cc" src="http://www.zermatt-fun.ch/images/mastercard.jpg" width=30 />
        </div>

  <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:0px">
                <input type='hidden' id='ccType' name='ccType'/>
            <ul class="cards">
            <li class="visa">Visa</li>
            <li class="visa_electron">Visa Electron</li>
            <li class="mastercard">MasterCard</li>
            <li class="maestro">Maestro</li>                   
            </ul>
              </div>
```

depeding on the value of the hidden input field ccType,I want to change the image src.
Th below code is not syntactically correct,its just a demonstration and a raw idea of what im trying to do

```
if (ccType=="visa")
{
change the image src to 'www.xyz.com/visa.png'
}
if( ccType=="maestro")
{
change image src to 'www.xyz.com/masestro/png'
}
```

the src inside

```
    <img id="cc" src="http://www.zermatt-fun.ch/images/mastercard.jpg" width=30 />
```

should be changed

Im trying to do this using a javascript.This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DMx8a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), it set attributes for the set of matched elements.

```
 $('#cc').attr('src', 'www.xyz.com/visa.png')
```

Code

```
if (ccType=="visa")
{
    $('#cc').attr('src', 'www.xyz.com/visa.png');
}
if( ccType=="maestro")
{
    $('#cc').attr('src', 'www.xyz.com/masestro/png');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DMx8a/3/)

### EDIT

```
$("#ccnumber").on('blur', function () {
    var ccType = $(this).val();
    if (ccType == "visa") {
        $('#cc').attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCHQ.png?s=32&g=1');
    }
    if (ccType == "maestro") {
        $('#cc').attr('src', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9edb7a1c14bbcbeaa16bd9149764c3c6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
    }
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DMx8a/4/) with **blur** event on ccnumber textbox

Comment: @user3128920, try http://jsfiddle.net/DMx8a/8/. Give some sample input for card type so that I test it at my end and delete all previous comments.

Comment: sample input is 404 starting will be "visa"  622 starting will be maestro

Comment: @user3128920, Used `$("#ccType").on('change', function () {` instead of `$("#ccnumber").on('blur', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Or just regular JS:

```
var image = document.getElementById("cc");
if (ccType=="visa")
{
    //change the image src to 'www.xyz.com/visa.png'
    image.src = 'www.xyz.com/visa.png'
}
if( ccType=="maestro")
{
    //change image src to 'www.xyz.com/masestro/png'
    image.src = 'www.xyz.com/masestro/png'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain javascript, go for the following:
`document.getElementById('cc').setAttribute('src', 'www.xyz.com/visa.png');`.

Like :

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById('cc');
if (ccType=="visa"){imageElement.setAttribute('src','www.xyz.com/visa.png');}
if( ccType=="maestro"){imageElement.setAttribute('src', 'www.xyz.com/masestro/png');}
```